# php Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity Source

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

whenever I use the following code in PHP files , it gives me the error (Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
Source)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
```

I don't know what could be the solution

please help

Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><rows><page>1</page><records>15</records><total>1</total><row id='18'><cell>18</cell><cell>2011-9-13</cell><cell>AL</cell><cell>2011-10-19</cell><cell>2011-10-21</cell><cell>3</cell><cell></cell><cell></cell><cell>Waiting for approval</cell><cell>mohan</cell><cell>Davinder Singh</cell></row><row id='17'><cell>17</cell><cell>2011-5-25</cell><cell>SL</cell><cell>2011-5-19</cell><cell>2011-5-19</cell><cell>1</cell><cell></cell><cell></cell><cell>Approved</cell><cell>Davinder</cell><cell>Kavita y</cell></row><row id='16'><cell>16</cell><cell>2011-5-25</cell><cell>SL</cell><cell>2011-5-24</cell><cell>2011-5-24</cell><cell>1</cell><cell></cell><cell></cell><cell>Approved</cell><cell></cell><cell>Kavita y</cell></row><row id='15'><cell>15</cell><cell>2011-5-26</cell><cell>AL</cell><cell>2011-7-08</cell><cell>2011-7-12</cell><cell>0</cell><cell></cell><cell></cell><cell>Disapproved</cell><cell></cell><cell>Kavita y</cell></row><row id='14'><cell>14</cell><cell>2011-5-25</cell><cell>AL</cell><cell>2011-6-30</cell><cell>2011-7-02</cell><cell>3</cell><cell></cell><cell></cell><cell>Approved</cell><cell></cell><cell>Kavita y</cell></row><row id='13'><cell>13</cell><cell>2011-9-14</cell><cell>CL</cell><cell>2011-6-15</cell><cell>2011-6-15</cell><cell>1</cell><cell></cell><cell></cell><cell>Waiting for approval</cell><cell></cell><cell>Kavita y</cell></row><row id='12'><cell>12</cell><cell>2011-5-25</cell><cell>CL</cell><cell>2011-6-10</cell><cell>2011-6-12</cell><cell>3</cell><cell></cell><cell></cell><cell>Waiting for approval</cell><cell></cell><cell>Kavita y</cell></row><row id='11'><cell>11</cell><cell>2011-5-25</cell><cell>SL</cell><cell>2011-5-20</cell><cell>2011-5-17</cell><cell>4</cell><cell></cell><cell></cell><cell>Waiting for approval</cell><cell></cell><cell>Kavita y</cell></row><row id='10'><cell>10</cell><cell>2011-5-25</cell><cell>CL</cell><cell>2011-6-03</cell><cell>2011-6-05</cell><cell>3</cell><cell></cell><cell></cell><cell>Waiting for approval</cell><cell>mohan</cell><cell>Davinder Singh</cell></row><row id='9'><cell>9</cell><cell>2011-5-26</cell><cell>SL</cell><cell>2011-5-18</cell><cell>2011-5-22</cell><cell>5</cell><cell></cell><cell></cell><cell>Waiting for approval</cell><cell>mohan</cell><cell>Davinder Singh</cell></row><row id='8'><cell>8</cell><cell>2011-5-24</cell><cell>AL</cell><cell>2011-5-20</cell><cell>2011-5-20</cell><cell>0</cell><cell></cell><cell></cell><cell>Disapproved</cell><cell>mohan</cell><cell>Davinder Singh</cell></row><row id='7'><cell>7</cell><cell>2011-5-24</cell><cell>CL</cell><cell>2011-5-20</cell><cell>2011-5-20</cell><cell>1</cell><cell></cell><cell></cell><cell>Waiting for approval</cell><cell>mohan</cell><cell>Davinder Singh</cell></row><row id='4'><cell>4</cell><cell>2011-9-14</cell><cell>SL</cell><cell>2011-5-20</cell><cell>2011-5-20</cell><cell>1</cell><cell></cell><cell></cell><cell>Waiting for approval</cell><cell>mohan</cell><cell>Davinder Singh</cell></row><row id='3'><cell>3</cell><cell>2011-5-24</cell><cell>SL</cell><cell>2011-5-20</cell><cell>2011-5-20</cell><cell>1</cell><cell></cell><cell></cell><cell>Waiting for approval</cell><cell>mohan</cell><cell>Davinder Singh</cell></row><row id='1'><cell>1</cell><cell>2011-5-24</cell><cell>SL</cell><cell>2011-5-20</cell><cell>2011-5-22</cell><cell>0</cell><cell>dd</cell><cell>remarks</cell><cell>Disapproved</cell><cell>mohan</cell><cell>Davinder Singh</cell></row></rows>
```

and the php code

```
header("Content-type: text/xml;charset=utf-8");

$s = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>";
$s .=  "<rows>";
$s .= "<page>".$page."</page>";
$s .= "<records>".$count."</records>";

$s .= "<total>".$total_pages."</total>";


// be sure to put text data in CDATA
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {


    $s .= "<row id='". $row['fld_id']."'>";

    $s .= "<cell>". $row['fld_id']."</cell>";   
    $s .= "<cell><![CDATA[". getDepartmentName($row['deptSr'])."]]></cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['email']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['fname']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['lname']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['password']."</cell>";

    $s .= "<cell>". listlevel($row['level'])."</cell>"; 
    $s .= "<cell>". date('Y-m-d G:i:s', $row['date_create'])."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". date('Y-m-d G:i:s', $row['last_login'])."</cell>";  
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['ip_addr']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['dob']."</cell>";  
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['street']."</cell>";       
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['phone_mob']."</cell>";        
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['phone_home']."</cell>";   
    $s .= "<cell>". liststatus($row['fld_enabled'])."</cell>";  

    $s .= "</row>";
}
$s .= "</rows>"; 

echo $s;
```

Comment: what is causing the error? PHP or some other tools? Is there any PHP code involved at all?

Comment: the records are coming from the database, and php gives the output in xml format. It's working on the one server, but no luck on the rest

Comment: ok, but what is giving the error? The browser? Or PHP? A certain piece of code? If it's not short_open_tag we need more information. Is there any whitespace or ByteOrder Marks before the XML prolog? Or are there any dangling prologs somewhere?

Comment: This thing here: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` is a [prolog.](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#sec-prolog-dtd) There should be only one of it. Also can you please check the source code of the result page that is giving you the error and make sure there is no whitespace or funny characters before the prolog.

Comment: ok, so should I remove it ?? but the same code is working on one server

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5042/discussion-between-dave-and-gordon)

Comment: Are you using WordPress? The reason I ask is because I did a search for the error message on Google and WordPress comes up in a lot of the results.

Comment: You still didn't supply the answer to **when you get this error**. Clearly it's not when you generate the XML, but rather when you try to consume it. How do you do that, what code is accessing this XML? Furthermore I don't get the four upvotes, given the "error+code=solution plz" inset of the question.

Comment: no it's not wordpress at all. it was coming after execution of the half of the page. anyways, the problem is solved.thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*XML or text declaration not at start of entity* indicates that the prolog isn’t the first line in the output. Most likely, a blank line is somehow finding its way into your output. This error isn’t unique to WordPress; however, as I mentioned in my comment, I did a search for the error message on Google and WordPress comes up in a lot of the results. If you’re not using WordPress, kindly disregard the remainder of this answer.

**Disclaimer:** I know *nothing* about WordPress so I’m reluctant to answer in that capacity; however, since there are no other answers as of this writing, I’ll simply show you what I’ve found on the subject.

- [Wordpress leading whitespace fix](http://wejn.org/stuff/wejnswpwhitespacefix.php.html) seems to help some people with the error you specified.
- [Additional suggestions are available here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/no-rss-xml-parsing-error).
- [How to fix: XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity](http://kaliphonia.com/content/misc/how-to-fix-xml-parsing-error-xml-or-text-declaration-not-at-start-of-entity) deals with white space before the prolog. The comment suggests using `ob_start()` and `ob_end_clean()`.

If you are using WordPress, you may attract better answers by adding the WordPress tag to your question. There’s no guarantee, but it could draw the attention of those more knowledgeable than myself.